# Auto-increment field on row edit in JqGrid for PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

In `JqSuite` for PHP, I am trying to auto-increment a field value everytime I submit a row edit.
My code is not working though!

**grid.php** excerpt:

```
$custom = <<<CUSTOM

var rowId;
var keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, errorfunc, afterrestorefunc;

function aftersavefunc(rowId, response) {
    alert("aftersavefunc Fired!");
    alert(rowId);

    $("#grid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'revision', '3');
}

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', rowId, keys, oneditfunc, 
        succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc, errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);

CUSTOM;
```

I don't even get the alert popup from `alert("aftersavefunc Fired!");`

Is anybody able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question: I just needed to use:

```
$cid = jqGridUtils::GetParam('my_id');

$grid->setAfterCrudAction('edit', "UPDATE my_table SET revision  = revision + 1 WHERE my_id=?",array($cid));
```